# How do I dynamically handle endless nested routes with Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

What if I have endless nested routes that don't stop (i.e. articles within articles based on user creation):

`/articles/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/id/infinity`

How do you handle something like that in Nuxt 3 without having to manually create each directory and dynamic file?

Comment: Only the last id matters right? That's the one you're fetching from the database and rendering in your top level router-view right? So your route is wrong correct?

Comment: Post your code so we can see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to use catch all routes for that. [Documentation and example.](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#catch-all-route)

Your pages structure is like this.

[image]

```
|-pages
|-articles = Folder
|--[...id].vue = Catch all routes
|--index.vue = Article Content 
|-articles.vue = NuxtPage
|-index.vue = Home page
```

`~pages/articles.vue`

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>

</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

`~/pages/articles/index.vue` Articles Content example

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>

</script>
<template>
  <div>
    Articles page
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

`~/pages/articles/[...id].vue` Dynamic ID

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>

const route = useRoute()
</script>
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Dynamic ID. Params: {{ route.params.id }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

Expected output.
[image]

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I just figured it out before coming to answer my own question. The fun part will trying to figure out how to grab the right id param for the page that you're on. Any ideas about how to do that?

Comment: If you want to get the ID value of the current page, you can do it like this. `route.params.id[route.params.id.length - 1]` . This gives you the last value of the array.